# Why there is no content-available parameter in the Push Transactional API in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, push

The Endpoint [Create Push Message](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/createPushMessage.html) has a JSON Parameter called content-available. It gives me the possible of send a [Silent Push Notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36694963/what-is-silent-push-notification-when-does-the-device-receive-it). Who do I apply the same feature in the [Transactional Push EndPoint](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/createSendDefinition.html)?